# Get the 'Last saved by' (windows file) with python

Tags: python, ms-office, metadata

How can I get the username value from the "Last saved by" property from any windows file?

e.g.: I can see this info right clicking on a word file and accessing the detail tab. See the picture below:

[image]

Does any body knows how can I get it using python code?

Comment: FYI, that is called file metadata. You might find something online with that search term

Comment: The [os package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) has a lot of file-handling methods, including how to retrieve file characteristics.

Comment: @user1558604, I could find a solution searching about metadata. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment from @user1558604, I searched a bit on google and reached a solution. I tested on extensions .docx, .xlsx, .pptx.

```
import zipfile
import xml.dom.minidom

# Open the MS Office file to see the XML structure.
filePath = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Perpetual-Draft-2019.xlsx"
document = zipfile.ZipFile(filePath)

# Open/read the core.xml (contains the last user and modified date).
uglyXML = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(document.read('docProps/core.xml')).toprettyxml(indent='  ')

# Split lines in order to create a list.
asText = uglyXML.splitlines()

# loop the list in order to get the value you need. In my case last Modified By and the date.
for item in asText:
    if 'lastModifiedBy' in item:
        itemLength = len(item)-20
        print('Modified by:', item[21:itemLength])

    if 'dcterms:modified' in item:
        itemLength = len(item)-29
        print('Modified On:', item[46:itemLength])
```

The result in the console is:

**Modified by: adm.UserName**

Modified On: 2019-11-08"