# Get file last modified by in Python (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, file

please, is there a way to find out who last changed an Excel file in windows using python?

Thanks a lot
John

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59338847/2570277) answer help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the 'Last saved by' (windows file) with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59257515/get-the-last-saved-by-windows-file-with-python)

Comment: Almost :). This will return my name, but I would need a username.